# Провайдер LINQ для SQLite

Tags: sqlite, linq2sql

Кто-нибудь видел расширение LINQ to SQL для SQLite? Есть ли вообще данное расширение (поддержка со стороны Sqlite)? Может кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DBLinq2007](http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/)

[http://kkubasik.wordpress.com/2007/10/25/sqllite-linq-provider/t](http://kkubasik.wordpress.com/2007/10/25/sqllite-linq-provider/)

http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/

Посмотрите здесь. В свое время очень помогло=)

Answer (score 2):

[dotConnect for SQLite](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/). Правда он платный.